# Как лучше всего реализовать регулярное выражение в Python3?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, url

Например имеем:

```
https://vk.com/publicname?z=video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY%2Fvideos-XXXXXXXXX%2Fpl_-XXXXXXXXX_-2
```

Сейчас пока что работает в таком формате:

```
url = url.split('z=', 1)[-1]
url = url.split('%2F', 1)[0]
url = "https://vk.com/" + url
>>>print(url)
https://vk.com/video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY
```

но понимаю, что это неправильно с точки зрения алгоритмизации. Допустим, если 'z=' со временем поменяется на что-то другое или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: В вк же ссылки всегда одного вида, можно и куда более простым способом:
print(url[0:15] + url[28:52])

Comment: ты не учел то, что publicname может принимать любое значение, собственно как и XXXXXXX и YYYYYY могут быть разной длины

Comment: а, просмотрел
ну тогда))
`print(a[0:a.find('?')]+'/' + a[a.find('video'):a.find('%')])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если со временем изменится `z=`, это будет серьезным изменением, и попытка предугадать его сейчас не обязательно приведет к успеху.

А вот на что точно не стоит полагаться в этом вопросе, так это на регулярные выражения.

Для любого веб приложения части строки запроса `?%7a=%30` и `?z=0` идентичны, тогда как для регулярного выражения, не посвященного в тонкости протокола, сходства в них нет.

Поэтому для декомпозиции урлов лучше пользоваться спец средствами.

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> url = "https://vk.com/publicname?z=video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY%2Fvideos-XXXXXXXXX%2Fpl_-XXXXXXXXX_-2"
```

```py
>>> result = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
>>> result
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='vk.com', path='/publicname', params='', query='z=video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY%2Fvideos-XXXXXXXXX%2Fpl_-XXXXXXXXX_-2', fragment='')
```

```py
>>> query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(result.query)
>>> query
{'z': ['video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY/videos-XXXXXXXXX/pl_-XXXXXXXXX_-2']}
```

```py
>>> path = query['z'][0].split('/')[0]
>>> path
'video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY'
```

```py
>>> newurl = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, urllib.parse.urljoin('/', path))
>>> newurl
'https://vk.com/video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY'
```

Единственный тонкий момент тут - разделение параметра `z` на компоненты с помощью `/`, но такой формат записи параметра прямого отношения к протоколу не имеет, поэтому требуется импровизация.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, как то так:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python

import re

regex = r'^.*(z=.*?%2).*$'
s1 = 'https://vk.com/publicname?z=video-XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYY%2Fvideos-XXXXXXXXX%2Fpl_-XXXXXXXXX_-2'

ro = re.compile(regex)
result = re.findall(ro,s1)

x = result[0]
url = "https://vk.com/" + x[2:-2]
print(url)
```

Comment: все работает, но опять таки вижу условие под "z=". Возможно ли как-то сделать, чтобы оно фильтровало так, чтобы начиналось именно с условия "video-" в начале, а не отсекало "z=" и то что перед ним?

Comment: @Oleg Внёс исправления в ответ.